# Find part of string in array, replace entire row with that part of string if found

Tags: c#, array

Following is the string: (I'm getting that from config file so its not constant):

```
string sequence = "Concat({ACCOUNT_NUM},substring(FormatDate(yyyyMMddHHmmss,DateNow())
,2,12), GetLast(GetNextSequence(seq_relation),1))";
```

It contains multiple custom methods and I want them somewhere in the same order as they appear in the above string. Following is the strategy I applied:

```
string[] arbitrary = sequence .Split('(').ToArray();

string[] methodsNmore = arbitrary.Take(arbitrary.Length - 1).ToArray();

string[] array2 = methodsNmore.Where(strr => strr.Contains(',')).ToArray();

string[] methods = array2.Select(str => str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf
                                         (',') + 1, str.Length - str.LastIndexOf
                                         (',') - 1)
                                        ).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
{
   string row = Array.Find(methodsNmore, item => item.Contains(methods[i]));

   int ii = Array.IndexOf(methodsNmore, row);

   methodsNmore[ii] = methods[i];
}
```

The resulting array, `methodsNmore`, now contains only the names of methods in the same order as in above string sequence.

Is there any other elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
string[] names =
  Regex.Matches(sequence, @"([A-Za-z_]\w*)\(").Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! I'm not that good at using Regex. Can you refer me the link which is easy to understand and in usage

Comment: @Sadiq: You can see what the parts of the regular expression means here: http://regex101.com/r/fQ8oK9

Comment: You even wrote under score in your regex what does it mean. Actually its working without it as well.

Comment: @Sadiq: An underscore is a valid character in an identifer, you could for example have a method named `get_last`. There are actually more characters that are valid in identifiers, but this covers the characters that are used in english.

Comment: Yes i got it now.. Your link really helped me .. Thanks again :)